# write multiprecision binary file with matlab

Tags: matlab, binary, fwrite

I would like to write a table with 1 integer followed by 3 doubles in binary format.
Of course I can just do a for loop

```
for i=1:sz
  fwrite(fid, integ(i), 'int');
  fwrite(fid, doubl(i,:), 'double');
end
```

but this is quite slow for arrays with a few million entries.
What is the most efficient way to handle this (without having to write a .mex)?

Unfortunately I must keep this [int32 float64 float64 float64] format, since this is a file format specification used by a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
So finally the fastest way to do it and respect the exact order and type of variable is to convert the table of `nx3 double` into an array of `(2xn)x3 int32`, reshape and concatenate the arrays then write everything in one go.

```
outfile4 = 'test1.bin' ;
tic4 = tic ;

% // reshape everything
table2write = int32(zeros(2*nCol+1,nPt)) ;
table2write(1,:) = integ.' ; %'
for k=1:nCol
   ixLine = (k-1)*2+2 ; 
   table2write( ixLine:ixLine+1 , : ) = reshape( typecast(doubl(:,k),'int32') , 2 , [] ) ;
end
% // write
fid = fopen( outfile4 , 'w' ) ;
count = fwrite(fid , table2write , 'int32' ) ;
fclose( fid ) ;
elapsed4 = toc(tic4)
```

Which result in:

```
elapsed4 =
   0.794346687070910
```

*<sub>read below to see the definition of test variables and slightly faster method but which deform the array</sub>*

---

**original answer:**
If you can afford to reorganize your file, you can gain a tremendous amount of time.

Consider the following example:

```
outfile1 = 'E:\TEMP\Z_ToDelete\test1.bin' ;
outfile2 = 'E:\TEMP\Z_ToDelete\test2.bin' ;

nPt = 0.5e6 ;
integ = int32( randi(32000,nPt,1) ) ;
doubl = rand(nPt,3) ;

%% // Write to file with mixed precision
tic1 = tic ;
fid = fopen( outfile1 , 'w' ) ;
for k = 1:nPt
  fwrite(fid, integ(k), 'int');
  fwrite(fid, doubl(k,:), 'double');
end
fclose( fid ) ;
elapsed1 = toc(tic1)

%% // write to file sequentially
tic2 = tic ;
fid = fopen( outfile2 , 'w' ) ;
fwrite(fid, integ, 'int');
fwrite(fid, doubl, 'double');
fclose( fid ) ;
elapsed2 = toc(tic2)
```

On my system, this output:

```
elapsed1 =
          19.7780466501241
elapsed2 =
        0.0309073378234669
```

So letting Matlab handle the writing of your full arrays, one precision at a time is extremely more efficient than specifying line by line what to write.

The downside is the reading of one single record from your saved file may be a little more complex, but you can easily write a function which for a given index will go to read the `integer`, skip the rest of them, then read the 3x`doubles`.

---

If you really cannot afford to multiplex/demultiplex your data, then you can consider converting your `int` to `double` and writing the full array:

```
tic3 = tic ;
A = [double(integ) doubl] ;
fid = fopen( outfile2 , 'w' ) ;
fwrite(fid, A, 'double');
fclose( fid ) ;
elapsed3 = toc(tic3)
```

This is still a lot faster than the initial "mixed precision" solution

```
elapsed3 =
         0.483094789081886
```

It will take you less time to convert them back to integer when you read them than you spent writing mixed precision values. The only downside of this method is a slight increase in file size (~ about 14%).

Comment: Thank you for the help! Unfortunately, it's an existing file format to be read by other programs that requires me to write [int32 float64 float64 float64]. Maybe I could produce an array byte by byte and write it in one go?

Comment: @serigado. Yes that's the last resort. I was hoping you wouldn't have to go there but indeed your last chance would be to convert each `double` in 2 column of _bit similar_ `int32`, then `fwrite` the whole table in one go.

Comment: Using num2hex, splitting and applying hex2dec is slower, even though it's cool. I can not believe there is not a way to accelerate this.

Comment: i am working on a solution with `typecast`, you should look at that too. It is better for type conversion. The only headache is to reshape the matrix in the correct format before writing.

Comment: That's beyond cool. Typecast is the ingenious command that I was missing. You might want to be careful because fopen with 'wb' means to write in big endian format. I also found that fopen(fn, 'W'), with a capital 'W' improves performance substantially. Thanks!

Comment: Ooops, my bad for the big endian format. Force of habit (Most of my binary file manipulations deal with an 8051 processor which is big endian). I corrected that. I am curious though, I tried a few different configurations with the `'W'` parameter but i didn't get any significant improvement.

Comment: For me the difference it's very visible when the fwrite is inside a for loop, but also when doing a sequential write: it's up to 60% faster. Both at work and at home machines. I test the 'W' before the 'w', and then the other way around, to avoid possible caching issues. The results are the same. I'm using Linux, though.

Comment: I tried a succession of alternating call. The very first call (whether it is `W` or `w`) is always slower, but then all the successive calls are about the same speed. Linux might make a difference though, or may be just the filesystem we are writing on (ext2/3/4, fat, ntfs etc ...). I'll do more testing at work.